# Motivation behind the definition of symmetric form.

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Define a bilinear form on $V$ is said to be symmetric iff $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle y,x\rangle$ for all $x,y\in V$.I want to know why suddenly people became interested in symmetric forms.What is the motivation behind studying symmetric forms?I am a graduate student studying bilinear forms and I have no idea about the motivation of symmetric forms.Does it come from the inner product or from somewhere else?

Comment: The standard dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a nice exmaple.

Comment: Yes, it's a *generalization* of the inner (=dot) product. If we drop the symmetricity condition, we get an even more general concept.

Comment: Every bilinear form (provided that we can divide by two in the base field) can be written as the sum of a symmetric form and an antisymmetric form. These forms are easier to study because (for example), their left and right annihilator spaces are equal: this leads to much less bookkeeping. Also, many natural forms are symmetric, such as $(A, B) \mapsto \mathrm{trace}(AB)$ on the space of $n \times n$ matrices.